# show three fragments on one activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-fragmentactivity, android-dialogfragment

[image]I am trying to show three different fragments on an `Activity` but when I run my code, my app crashes and the logical does not find any error. what could be the problem?

This is my java file which contains the three fragments

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class Gallery extends Activity {
Fragment fragmenta;
Fragment fragmentb;
Fragment fragmentc;
FragmentManager fm;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gallery);
    fm = getFragmentManager();
    fragmenta=new FragmentA();
    fragmentb=new FragmentB();
    fragmentc=new FragmentC();
    fragmenta=(Fragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.layout.fragmenta);
    fragmentb=(Fragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.layout.fragmentb);
    fragmentc=(Fragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.layout.fragmentc);


}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

If you are using android support v4, your **Gallery** shall extend `FragmentActivity`

```
public class Gallery extends Activity {
```

should be

```
public class Gallery extends FragmentActivity {
```

Comment: my android studio does not have that option to extend the class to.

Comment: what ? how is that possible , try rebuild your project  or else just copy from above

Comment: theres a spelling mistake... "FragmentActivity"

Comment: He will also need to use getSupportFragmentManager() too if he's using v4

Comment: look at the image i put up, it won't let me extend to FragmentActivity

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27012147/android-studio-cant-resolve-fragmentactivity-and-viewpager-imports