# Cannot access android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb

Tags: android

I implemented an Android application using `support.v7.app.AppcompatActivity`. This application doesn't compile: when I hold my mouse cursor above the `super` key it shows the following error:

```
Cannot access android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb
```

[image: Android Studio screenshot]

Comment: So, what's the question? Also, post some code.

Comment: Sorry, I do not know how to display the image. You can click on the **code screenshot**.

Comment: I've edited your post to include the image. When you create a question, there is a toolbar for formatting. This contains a button to insert (upload) an image.

Comment: I think you do not need the `BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb` class: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20388380/2715720) and the [api](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html) doesn't include this class either

Comment: found solution for this?

Comment: have a similar problem my error hint is 'cannot access android.support.v4.BaseFragmentAcitivityEclair'

Comment: Found a solution to this?

Comment: did you get any proper solution?

Answer (score 6):

I've a same problem.
And my resolution is:

Replace project dependencies:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
```

}

with

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.0.0'
```

}

It works for me,good luck.

Comment: you mean replace `support:design` with `support-annotations`?

Answer (score 0):

It seems a compile issue. Try to check File -> project structure ->project -> set Gradle version and Android plugn version,then rebuild the project.

I found out the hidden issue by the operation.