# Cannot resolve symbol 'ViewCompat'

Tags: android, android-support-library, support-v4

Complete gradle file, and even unable to resolve the symbol 'AppCompatActivity'.
Don't understand what's wrong.

Already tried options ::
1) Clean and Rebuild
2) Invalidate/Catches and Restart

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.bintray'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation project(':blocklylib-core')
    implementation project(':blocklylib-vertical')
}
```

Comment: post ur whole gradle

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio and android.support.v4.app.Fragment: cannot resolve symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20386331/android-studio-and-android-support-v4-app-fragment-cannot-resolve-symbol)

Comment: Try to import `import android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat;`

Comment: @BrijeshJoshi question edited

Comment: @NileshRathod unable to import it

Comment: delete `.idea` , `.iml` and `/build/`

Comment: @Mr.Roshan yes tried everything from the same url but not working in my case.

Comment: delete all except `rootdir/app`

Comment: @AndroidGuy  test case `allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
       
    }
}
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this in your build.gradle file-

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:26.0.2'
```

Now,
**Delete "/.idea/libraries" and then synced with gradle and built again.**

Answer (score 4):

For SDK 27 and higher use **import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat;**

Answer (score 2):

**Retype the AppCompatActivity in MainActivity/Classes**

And delete old imports in your MainActivity/Classes