# How to remove "cannot resolve symbol" for already added dependencies

Tags: android, android-studio

I am receiving a "can not find symbol" error for dependencies which are already added to the project

The app is running on android studio 3.1, and it compiles and runs normally, as if there are no dependency issues. I tried clearing gradle cache with the cleanBuildCache command, and I also invalidate the cache from File > Invalidate Cache/Restart but to no avail.

Import error in red

[image: The error in question]

Support libraries under dependency on the right, but not showing in external 
    libs on the left

[image: external library and dependency]

Comment: What version of Gradle are you using ? You can check that in gradle-wrapper.properties file under distributionUrl. Doesn't it gives you an error that  `complie` keyword has been deprecated ?

Comment: It seems that this is just an IDE not syncing with gradle issue and already been asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20386331/android-studio-and-android-support-v4-app-fragment-cannot-resolve-symbol/33631619

Comment: You can also try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21100688/android-studio-suddenly-cannot-resolve-symbols/21100896#21100896

Answer (score 1):

Try doing the following:

- Save your project and close Android Studio
- DELETE ***Project Name.iml*** file from you project directory
- DELETE **app.iml** file from your ***Project Name***/app directory
- DELETE **.idea** folder from your project directory

**Project Name** is the name of the project that you set when you first created your project in Android Studio.

Relaunch Android Studio, load your project ,sync gradle and build again.

*NOTE:* You might have to be connected to internet as it will download the libraries again that were delete when deleting the **.idea** folder

Also update your gradle verions and use `implementation` instead of `compile` as  it was deprecated long ago.

Comment: This doesn't work; All the classes the OP is trying to import doesn't have the correct dependency

Comment: See my answer. He's not using AppCompat in the imports in his picture.

Comment: he is using appcompat-v7 which also depends on support-v4 (but he included it anyway) which contains all the classes he is importing. See here the list of classes support-v4 contains https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/package-summary.html.

Comment: I can tell you don't understand my comment and/or you haven't looked at my answer. Let me clarify. He is missing the `com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0` dependency and that is what is causing the red import statements in Android Studio.

Comment: The library you mentioned `support-compat:26.1.0` is one part of `support-v4`. In other words including `support-v4` implies that `support-compat:26.1.0` along with all the parts v4 Support Libraries are included. See here https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages#v4

Comment: You are right... But then both our answers still don't work. Using the same support libraries and import statements as the OP I get identical results.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195830/discussion-between-syed-ahmed-jamil-and-divergence).

Comment: @Divergence check my last message in the chat. I ran your project did some tweaks and it runs now there were some trivial typos.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Build > Clean Project?  Or a good old fashioned restart of Android Studio?

Comment: What about restarting android studio?